# Please help me complete my proof? (Based on H.C.F of integers)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

> If $a$ and $b$ are positive integers, then $a = bq + r$, $0 \leq r < b$, where $q$ is a whole number. Prove that $\text{HCF}(a, b) = \text{HCF}(b, r)$.

I have proceeded as follows:

Let $\text{HCF}(a, b) = h$. So, $b = mh$ and $r = nh$ where $m$ and $h$ are co-primes. What to do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(bq+r, b) = \gcd(bq+r-bq, b) = \gcd(b,r)$$

You have to use the property that $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a, b+ka)$